# Italian immigrant vital records

Tags: vital-records, italy

Seeking Italian church records (birth, marriage, death) dating back to late 1800's for ancestors who immigrated to USA from Alessandria del Carretto, Italy.

Answer (score 1):

The vital records that you are after would seem likely to be found using the [links at FamilySearch.org](https://www.familysearch.org/search/catalog/518043?availability=Family%20History%20Library):

> **Registri dello stato civile di Alessandria del Carretto (Cosenza), 1809-1910**
>
> **Authors**: Alessandria del Carretto (Cosenza). Ufficio dello stato civile (Main Author) Archivio di stato di Cosenza (Repository)
>   Tribunale di Castrovillari (Repository)
>
> **Format**: Manuscript/Manuscript on Film
>
> **Language**: Italian  Publication: Salt Lake City, Utah : Filmati dalla Genealogical Society of Utah, 1986-1996
>
> **Physical**: in 9 bobine di microfilm ; 16 mm.
>
> **References**: (Digital Collection) Italy, Cosenza, Castrovillari, civil registration (Tribunale) = Italia, Cosenza, Castrovillari, stato
>   civile (Tribunale), 1866-1910